# Is it possible to upload an X client to a Linux server and show it like a website?

Tags: c, web, xlib

X protocol is a network-based model, and an X client can communicate with an X server via Net,  so is it possible to upload an X client to a Linux server and show it like a website?

Comment: Very close question [x windows in a browser. ajaxterm but with X](http://superuser.com/questions/255931/x-windows-in-a-browser-ajaxterm-but-with-x.). Looks like there is no such product yet.